# How do I use this CSS animation in my HTML file?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm just new to CSS and I want to run this particular animation but not sure yet how to call it in my html file
http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/css3-animated-scene/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in the CSS code in a file named `style.css
Then include it as shown:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Place `style.css and a HTML page, for example`page.html in the same folder and open `page.html. Should work :)

I have set up a JS fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/kr2XU/

Answer (score 1):

You have to `link` your CSS in the HTML file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

For the future, you should know very easy and good way of animating content in your HTML files is using an Adobe product called Edge Animate. It is available with a free Creative Cloud membership.

You can learn more about it [here](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/).

About calling CSS selectors, let's have an example:

```
main.css

.class1 
{
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#another_selector 
{
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

In your HTML file, you will have:

```
<div class="class1"> This div has the CSS class ".class1" </div>
<div id="another_selector"> This div has the "#another_selector" id </div>
```

See [here a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2m7q9/) that will help you figure out what's going on with those classes and ids.